# Translate an ojbect on its local axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm very beginner to three.js and I try to translate an object imported from Maya;the problem is that after rotation, if I try to move it, it moves along the scene's axis and not in the direction of the rotation.

This is what I tried to do:

```
var keyCode = event.which;

// up
if (keyCode == 87) {
    shuttle.translateZ(0.2);
    // down
} else if (keyCode == 83) {
    shuttle.translateZ(-0.2);
        // left
} else if (keyCode == 65) {
    shuttle.rotation.y-= 0.1;
      // right
} else if (keyCode == 68) {
    shuttle.rotation.y += 0.1;
  }
```

It makes no difference if I use the function translateZ or shuttle.position.z+=1 .

Comment: You are trying move the object in the global axis, you need to apply the rotation to the translation vector.

Comment: this seemingly works for me, see this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmBBbo
can you supply more code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to translate along the direction of the object

```
var direction = shuttle.getWorldDirection();
shuttle.translate(direction.multiplyScalar(distance) );
```